# Extracting multiple sections of text from google sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to grab a subset of covid data from a cell in google sheets that contains a lot of superfluous data.

Specifically, [the LDH vaccine information tab here](https://ldh.la.gov/Coronavirus/) has a tab containing "Vaccination by Gender by Parish" which has two things repeated 64 times: A line containing information on total series initiated and completed per parish, and a chart showing the percentage breakdowns by gender for that parish.

I'm importing this tab by copy/pasting into a google form (splitting it in 2 halfway through to get around the character limit). It returns a massive cell (or, two cells rather) containing 32(x2) instances of both the lines containing parish vaccine data and several lines containing the chart data.

Is there a way I'm not seeing to create an array formula that will isolate the two segments? I don't need the gender breakdown information, just the top-line numbers per parish. If I can get the top-line numbers into a separate cell together, I can use a split function on them, but can't separate everything correctly using the split function from a single cell.

This is the shortest of three lists/charts that display the information as a raw string (on the front-facing side, which I need to use because other people will be inputting this data into the sheet).

Edit: [Here's a viewable version of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWxMkp9cs6srMVaIacvi3bxXQuUJUCzndOW6v8nirOs/edit?usp=sharing).

To get to the correct tab, click "Vaccination Information" at the top of the ArcGIS dashboard. Then, click the left arrow at the bottom of the dashboard until it displays "Vaccination by Gender by Parish."

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Where is **Vaccination by Gender by Parish** tab exactly?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are now using copy-paste to import data. Do you want the data to be loaded into the sheet automatically using import functions such as IMPORTHML ()? or a script? If so, it will not be easy to do, because the data is displayed on the page using a javascript. You can see for yourself if you disable javascript on the source page.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried scraping the data but have come to the conclusion that it's too difficult to manage, especially on a project that other people are contributing to when I'm not able to. It's a simple copy/paste job into a google form that imports into the sheet. My goal is to separate the data once it's in the google sheet without creating a stupid amount of useless rows.

Comment: Can you break down your problem to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The source data is not there where you say.Would you create an image or screen-cast of how to get the source data?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not possible to use automatic import using formulas and you have to use copy-paste, you can get the result you want faster [this way](https://youtu.be/RaSoSjCtWJ0).

1. Copy from the site and paste the data on the sheet.
2. Filter and remove unnecessary rows.
3. Split the text into columns using the "-" separator.
4. Search and replace, remove text and spaces from the data columns.